# PHP - get object parent

Tags: php, class, object

I have a function that is called like this:

```
foo($object->ID);
```

and in the function I need to somehow select `$object` if `$object->ID` is passed as a variable.

```
function foo($id = NULL){
  if($id != NULL) ... // here I want to get $object
  else ...
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, why not just pass the object itself by ref?

```
function foo(&$obj)
{
    if($obj != NULL && $obj->ID != NULL)
    {
       // ...process your stuff 
    }
}
```

My PHP's pretty rusty, but I'm fairly sure that's how you pass by ref...

Comment: Pass-by-ref is not relevant in this case.

Comment: I should clarify: You want to make sure that you pass the object by reference so that you don't make an entirely new copy of it.

Comment: well the reason is pretty stupid :) I have a set of functions that all but this one take the `$object->id` as argument. And it looks ugly if just this one didn't :)

Comment: since php 5 (maybe earlier than that), objects are always passed by reference - no need to explicitly pass objects by ref.

Comment: @CommanderZ: how is it not relevant? You'd always want to pass complex objects by ref to avoid duplication (and potentially unexpected behavior)

Comment: @Alex: Unfortunately, that's the only way to do it. As you're passing a numeric value in your function param, there's no way for the client function to figure out where it came from.

Comment: There's a typo: it should be `$obj`, not `&obj` on line 3.

Answer (score 5):

That is not possible. You are passing a number without any information about its origin. Do this

```
foo($object)

function foo($object){
   if($object->ID !== null) ... // work with $object
   else ... // work with ID

}
```

Answer (score 4):

why not:

```
foo($object);
```

and

```
function  foo($localObject){
  if(isset($localObject->id)){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the object in as an argument instead of the ID.

Comment: You should just pass the object in, and get ID from that object, not add another parameter.